# What's wrong with my Javascript for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

Here is the content of my HTML-body:

```
<body> 
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<table style="width:100%" id="theTable"> 
<thead id="head">
<tr>
    <th>@id</th>
    <th>@author</th>
    <th>@content</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="body">
<tr >
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot id="foot"></tfoot>
</table>
<button onclick="notMyFunction()">+</button>
<script src="first_js.js"> </script>
</body>
```

And this is my js-Code:

```
    function notMyFunction(){
//Access the children of the table
        var x = document.getElementById("theTable").children;   
//Insert a row    
        var z = x[1].insertRow(0); 
//Access the indexes of the rows
        var y = x[1].rows.length-1;    
//The number of the cells in the last row                            
        var l = x[1].rows[y].cells.length;                  
//Test if everything working properly
//This seems to be the case because y++ with everz click and l=3 for ever         
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=y;
        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML=l;
//create a new <input> for the new-added row
    var newInput = document.createElemet("input");
    newInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
//This loops seems to be incorrect
    for (var i = 0, m=l; i < m ; i++) {
        x[1].rows[0].insertCell(i);
        x[1].rows[0].cells[i].appendChild(newInput);
    }
    }
```

It must be a table which rows can be added dynamic.
but the createElement-part, making it possible to add new rows with input-cells doesn't work, and I can't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: You have a non-standard for loop there.  It only takes 3 params: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @jmargolisvt He only has 3 parameters. You're allowed to initialize multiple variables in the firs tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending the same `<input>` element into each cell. `appendChild()` doesn't make a copy of the element, it simply appends it to the new cell, which means it has to be removed from the previous cell. You need to use `document.createElement()` in the loop to make a new input.

You also had a typo: `createElemet`.

Full code:

```js
function notMyFunction() {
  //Access the children of the table
  var x = document.getElementById("theTable").children;
  //Insert a row    
  var z = x[1].insertRow(0);
  //Access the indexes of the rows
  var y = x[1].rows.length - 1;
  //The number of the cells in the last row                            
  var l = x[1].rows[y].cells.length;
  //Test if everything working properly
  //This seems to be the case because y++ with everz click and l=3 for ever         
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = l;
  for (var i = 0, m = l; i < m; i++) {
    //create a new <input> for the new-added row
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    x[1].rows[0].insertCell(i);
    x[1].rows[0].cells[i].appendChild(newInput);
  }

}
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<table style="width:100%" id="theTable">
  <thead id="head">
    <tr>
      <th>@id</th>
      <th>@author</th>
      <th>@content</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="foot"></tfoot>
</table>
<button onclick="notMyFunction()">+</button>
```

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your help, you have rescued me